# Implementing a for loop in SQL to update rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do I write the below code in SQL? The query would update each column in the table from the result.

```
DECLARE @table_list NVARCHAR -- What data type do I use to hold a list?
DECLARE @column_list NVARCHAR

SET @table_list = (SELECT DISTINCT [ID_TABLE_NAME] FROM dbo.VMO) -- there are more than one results 
SET @column_list = (SELECT DISTINCT [USR_COL_NAME] FROM dbo.VMO) -- there are more than one results 

foreach(@table IN @table_list)
{
    foreach(@column IN @column_list)
    {
        UPDATE @table
        SET @column = '101211'
        WHERE @column = '10120'
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do then? Do you want to `SELECT` the new table list?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the purpose of the operation done inside the loop. Can you please elaborate your question more?

Comment: I don't think T-SQL supports for loop, perhaps it has a WHILE loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CURSORs to act like a foreach loop:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(255)

DECLARE OUTER_CURSOR CURSOR 
FOR SELECT DISTINCT [ID_TABLE_NAME] FROM dbo.VMO

OPEN OUTER_CURSOR 

FETCH NEXT FROM OUTER_CURSOR INTO @table
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN

        DECLARE INNER_CURSOR CURSOR 
        FOR SELECT DISTINCT [USR_COL_NAME] FROM dbo.VMO

        OPEN INNER_CURSOR 

        FETCH NEXT FROM INNER_CURSOR INTO @column

        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
        BEGIN


            DECLARE @strQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) 
            SET @strQuery = 'UPDATE [' + @table + '] SET [' + @column + '] = ''101211'' WHERE [' + @column + '] = ''10120'';'

            EXEC(@strQUERY)

            FETCH NEXT FROM INNER_CURSOR INTO @column

        END

        CLOSE INNER_CURSOR
        DEALLOCATE INNER_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM OUTER_CURSOR INTO @table

END

CLOSE OUTER_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE OUTER_CURSOR
```

Answer (score -1):

T-SQL doesn't have a `FOR loop`, perhaps it has a [WHILE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Use SQL like below:**

```
DECLARE @table_list NVARCHAR -- What data type do I use to hold a list?
DECLARE @column_list NVARCHAR

SET @table_list = (SELECT DISTINCT [ID_TABLE_NAME] FROM dbo.VMO) -- there are more than one results 
SET @column_list = (SELECT DISTINCT [USR_COL_NAME] FROM dbo.VMO) -- there are more than one results 

WHILE @column_list > @table_list
BEGIN
  UPDATE @table
        SET @column = '101211'
        WHERE @column = '10120'
END;
```